# How to eager-load has_one associations on STI subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model hierarchy like this:

```
class Activity
end

class HelloActivity < Activity
  has_one :hello_activity_details
end

class WorldActivity < Activity
  has_one :world_activity_details
end
```

I want to query all activities and eager load the details to avoid the N+1 issue. However, doing:

```
Activity.all.include([:hello_activity_details, :world_activity_details])
```

Yields

```
Association named 'hello_activity_details' not found on WorldActivity; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

How can I load the details?

I know I can invoke the preloader manually, but is there a more idiomatic way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typical typo error, as the error states.

`has_one` must have the class association name as **singular**.

Try:

```
class HelloActivity < Activity
  has_one :hello_activity_detail
end

class WorldActivity < Activity
  has_one :world_activity_detail
end
```